# $|A \cup B| \leq |A| + |B|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Let $|A| = n$ and $|B| = m$. Wlog, we can assume that $n \leq m$. I proved the following result $|A \cup \{x\} | \leq n + 1$.
I will use this result. Since B is non-empty we have element $y_1$ in $B$. Then it follows that $|A \cup \{y_1\}| = n + 1$. Consider the set $A_1 \leq A \cup \{y_1\}$. Applying the above argument gives us $A_2$. After m steps we have $A_{m}$ such that $A_m = A \cup B$ such that $|A_m| \leq n + 1$.

Comment: The idea is to keep adding elements of B to A and so $A\cup \{y_1 \} \cup... \cup \{y_m \} $ and then this has less than $n+m$ elements as a set. You have done this but you haven't written everything correctly, you need to put $|A_m|\leq n+m $.

Comment: Yes this is my proof above isn't it ?

Comment: @joeblacksmith Notice that this $y_1$ in general exists only if $m>n$ otherwise the set $A$ and $B$ could be equal, and such $y_1$ do not add any new element to $A$.

Comment: @Valerin is there a way to fix this proof I can't think of a way atm.

Comment: @joeblacksmith Yes, I will update my answer rigorously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ and $B$ finite sets, then $$|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B| $$
Notice that the set $A\cup B$ is formed by the $n$ elements of $A$ plus the $m$ elements of $B$. But some of the elements of $B$ have already been accounted for, this is precisely the case of $|A\cap B|$ elements of $A\cap B$, that's why we must subtract them. Since $-|A\cap B|\leq 0$ we have $$|A\cup B|\leq |A|+|B| $$ Maybe in future this can be helpful: if $f:A\to B$ is inyective then $|A|\leq |B|$. Here I will provide a different argument:
$A\cup B$ can be expressed as a disjoint union $$A\cup B = (A\backslash B)\cup (B\backslash A)\cup (A\cap B)  $$ therefore we have $$|A\cup B|=|A\backslash B|+|B\backslash A|+|A\cap B| $$ Since $A$ is the disjoint union of $A\backslash B$ and $A\cap B$ we have $$|A|=|A\backslash B|+|A\cap B| \Rightarrow |A \backslash B|=|A|-|A\cap B|$$ similarly $$|B\backslash A|=|B|-|A\cap B| $$ Replacing we have $$|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B| $$ from which your result follows.

Comment: what about my proof above?

Comment: @joeblacksmith check this one updated.